# Gulp rigger not work

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bower

[Structure my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyHgJ.png)

Not work gulp-rigger, dont understand why. Way with file include //= /template/footer.html
Link my project https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZWvBK7NX05YvlPWQeMzWfYh6RX77eP7G

```
    var gulp         = require('gulp');
gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.html)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: can you clarify a little bit more. It's hard to understand when you've posted a  5 liner snippet and a half of a screenshot.

Comment: @ZombieChowder attached a link to the project

Comment: Where do you call task "html:build" - I don't see a call to it.  And add a return statement to it.